# Laravel e Front-End

Tags: php, laravel-5, angular

Bem , queria a opinião de alguns dev's que ja passaram pelo mesmo dilema que estou passando agora, não sei se esse é o canal certo para realizar essa pergunta.

Tenho que construir uma aplicação, estou querendo fazer ela em Laravel, para o backEnd é muito boa, mas estou com dúvidas se o Laravel me atenderia no frontEnd, vi que tem como anexar ao projeto um template pronto, isso ajuda muito. Mas gostaria de saber se na parte frontEnd é recomendado fazer com uma linguagem front como o Angular, ou o Laravel atende bem ? Enfim, O laravel é bom para front-End ? Pois minha aplicação precisa ser muito dinâmica e passar uma boa experiencia para o usuário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu recomendaria utilizar um Framework próprio para o front-end já que como você mesmo disse, precisa passar uma boa experiencia para o usuário, e telas atualizando não é tão legal.

Além de que eu acredito que seja melhor separar o front-end e back-end de forma bem explicita, em que o front-end apenas seja nutrido pelas rotas do back-end, sem nenhuma ligação entre eles.

Acredito que separando dessa forma fica mais fácil a manutenção futura e até o entendimento do projeto, já que vai estar utilizando um framework focado e próprio para o front-end.

Atualmente onde trabalho é utilizado o Angular, porém um framework que eu tenho mais simpatia é o [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/).

Comment: Valeu Lucas.. Estou querendo fazer com um framework front, mas queria saber pois o laravel tem algum suporte pra front, pois agilizaria ainda mais o desenvolvimento, mas não vale a pena mesmo, e pelo que vc falou me ajudou a tomar minha decisão. valeu!

Comment: @MarlonCastro Oque eu acho o mais correto mesmo é apenas o back suprir o front com dados, acho que isso vai te ajudar na manutenção futura.